# What exactly are those "furby-balls" in Dog Days?

Tags: dog-days

In Dog Days, when "normal" inhabitants get knocked out, they turn into "balls" that look like a cats with large heads and short limbs. (similar to the [Furby toy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furby))

[image][image]

[image]

On other hand, when the main characters get knocked out, they look pretty normal (by Anime standards).

[image][image]

<sub>*Put aside the fact that a main character that is knocked out is usually striped of his/her clothes for no apparent reason other than fan-service.</sub>

So my questions are:

- What's the proper name for these "furby-balls"?
- How are these "normal" inhabitants different from the main characters?
- Do they "recover" back into human-like inhabitants?

Comment: I will make a proper awnser soon. I can tell you a few things allready. the name for those "furby balls" is told in the anime. i need te rewatch the series to get the name(think it was in the first few episodes when they are explaining to cinque how the battles worked). and to the question if they recover back to human beings. yes they do

Comment: Fanservice is a valid reason, isn’t it? ;)

Comment: The fur balls in the second season are refered to as 'beast balls'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have been trying to get a satisfying answer for myself for this question, but it has proven to be very hard.

For your **first question** there is no real name for them as far as I can see. I have looked at the episode (episode 2 around 4:00 minute mark) to see how the different subbers named them.

[image: I don't know the subber]
[image: Ruri subs]

So as you can see one of them names it "animal furballs" and the other names it "pet balls". What info I can give you on it else is:

- The people from Biscotti turn into "Dog looking balls"
- The people from Gallete turn into "Cat looking balls"
- The people from Pastillage (season 2) turn into "Squirrel looking balls"

For the normal inhabitants can turn into the animal balls the following ways:

- When they have been hit hard with a weapon (KO/unconscious)
- When they get touched on the back or head

For your **second question** I have tried to look up information, but not much is said about it in the anime or is found on the web about it. The only thing I have been able to find about it is this:

> It may be part of the protection magic. High-ranking fighters lose
>   their clothes. Everyone else turns into a furball. A pretty blatant
>   example of this happens in episode 9 of the first season. Vert Far
>   Breton shoots a magical arrow which hits Ricotta while she's flying
>   above them. Ricotta loses all of her clothes except her panties, and
>   then a magical spear hurled at Vert's troops knocks them all out, but
>   only strips her armor/clothing off.

Source: [here](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/DogDays) under "Clothing Damage".

The **third question** is by far the easiest to answer. If you watch the second episode about at the same time mark I mentioned in the first question you will see them saying something in the lines of:

> They will be rendered powerless for a limited time.

During this time that they are in their "ball form" the medics of the teams will "collect" them and bring them to the base camp of their team.

Comment: As a side note the original term for there fur-ball are "[けものだま](http://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%81%91%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0%E3%81%BE)" as in 獣玉 or "beast balls"

Comment: My theory on the second question is basically that: knights and royalty have significantly stronger armor that can absorb a lot. If pressed on after destroying the armor, one probably could KO them completely, transforming them into "beast balls". However, it's probably considered polite or courteous to let them retreat instead and rejoin the battle later (since clashes between the "high-level" combatants are the main entertainment for the crowd at home).